# Plausibility of 30 gauge draw?

Tags: blood, hematology, venous-system, needles, hemolysis

What are the risks, complications, and problems associated with using a 30 gauge needle to draw blood from someone with otherwise average veins? What is the certainty of hemolysis and would it be even possible to syringe draw with a 30 gauge needle?